# Attempting to Run the Find Closest Facility Tool Within Python For Loop

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, closest-facility

While using ArcGIS Pro, I am trying to run the Find Closest Facility tool inside a Python For loop. I found some helper code in the tool information rollover in Pro that goes through these steps:

```
username = "<your user name>"
password = "<your password>"
cf_service = "https://www.arcgis.com".format(username, password)


#Add the geoprocessing service as a toolbox. Use an alias when importing
arcpy.ImportToolbox(cf_service, "agol")

#Set the variables to call the tool
facilities = r"C:/data/Inputs.gdb/Stores"
incidents = r"C:/data/Inputs.gdb/Customers"
output_routes = "C:/data/Results.gdb/Routes"
output_directions = "C:/data/output/Results.gdb/Directions"

#Call the tool
result = arcpy.agol.FindClosestFacilities(incidents, facilities, "Minutes", "", 2)
```

After entering my user/pass, I tried to import the Find Closest Facilities tool from AGOL and was presented with this error:

"OSError: The toolbox file http://logistics.arcgis.com/arcgis/services;World/ClosestFacilty;<*username*>;<*password*> was not found."

My user account is an Admin so I should have privileges to call this tool from AGOL to run inside of a Python script. Perhaps, I'm calling it incorrectly? I tried using the URL above, as well as, our AGOL portal URL.

What I'm ultimately trying to do is to just run the "FindClosestFacilties" tool in a Python script, so if anyone has an alternative to the above Esri code, that would be helpful.

Comment: I've not attempted to use the tool you are using or familiar with calling server side tools but just looking at the error message I would have as a guess that it's the ; between services and World that is upsetting things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code fragment for the following is incomplete:

```
cf_service = "https://www.arcgis.com".format(username, password)
#Add the geoprocessing service as a toolbox. Use an alias when importing
arcpy.ImportToolbox(cf_service, "agol")
```

I'd take another look at the [ImportToolbox](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/importtoolbox.htm) help.

If you're inside Pro **or** outside Pro *and* logged in, you can use the following... the **UseSSOIdentityIfPortalowned** makes use of being logged in to get a token and authenticate. This will be the easiest to get up and running.

```
tbx = "http://logistics.arcgis.com/arcgis/services;World/ServiceAreas;UseSSOIdentityIfPortalOwned"
arcpy.ImportToolbox(tbx)
```

Based on your code, you're passing a username and password. You can only use the username/password input syntax if you're connecting directly to an ArcGIS Server. In your snippet you're pointing at ArcGIS.com, this is a Portal. So you're mixing and matching code snippets from the ImportToolbox. If you want to pass the user/pass like you are, you'll need to create an .AGS connection file to a server that makes use of the logistic service. (Instead of a http url like you have). If you want to use the Portal (arcgis.com) version, you'll need to obtain a token and can use that syntax from the help link referenced above. You can get a token in Python, or if you're signed in using Pro, you can use `arcpy.GetSigninToken()` to obtain one.

Comment: Looks like UseSSOIdentityIfPortalowned did the trick. Thanks @KHibma!